# How to disable BIOS editing while being able to boot without a password?

Tags: bios, uefi

Is there any way to disable BIOS/UEFI editing as well as the boot menu, while still being able to boot the computer without entering a password?

I have Gigabyte B450 Aorus Elite motherboard.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edit boot menu to load only from desired source. And add admin password (which is in charge only when you want to login in BIOS, not in boot process)

Comment: As it turned out in my case, the "Security Option", which was set to "System" by default, was getting in the way. This was causing a password request even when only the administrator password was set. I set it to "Setup" and got rid of the password prompt at system boot. So the problem is now solved. Anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In BIOS, You can set up two types of passwords:

- **Administrator Password**: The Computer will prompt this password only when you are trying to access the BIOS. It is used to prevent others from changing the BIOS settings.
- **System Password**: This will be prompted before the operating system can boot up. It can stop someone from powering up your computer.

Setting the Administrator Password, but not setting the System Password,
will let users freely boot the computer. But they will not be able to
change any BIOS setting, since entering the BIOS will require the
Administrator Password.

Comment: As it turned out in my case, the "Security Option", which was set to "System" by default, was getting in the way. This was causing a password request even when only the administrator password was set. I set it to "Setup" and got rid of the password prompt at system boot. So the problem is now solved. Anyway thanks for your reply.